# iOS - UIScrollVIew with layers

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uiscrollview, layer

Does someone have an example of using a UIScrollView that contains a layer that is playing a CAKeyFrameAnimation or some thing close?

I have the animation playing in there but it doesn't seem to recognize the pinch zoom, I followed a guide for UIImages but the zoom function is specifying a UIView to zoom in on and I would like to zoom in on the layer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another guide I found with UIImages... Easy enough to figure out from there I think.

http://www.austinbull.com/tutorials/tutorial3.zip